# How can I write a .then function with async/await, so that I can catch the response from axios (in seperate files and methods, in vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, axios

My target is to catch a respone, from a axios request, which works greate with .then, but I would like use async/await, since it is a new approach with lots of benefits.
(The update method is called multiple times)

How transform my saveEdit method (which gets a response form the update method) with async/await, so that I can catch the response from axios.

Method of my .vue file:

```js
...
saveEdit (event, targetProperty, updateValue) {
  this.update(this[updateValue])
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.status === 200) {
        this.fetchData()
        this.cancelEdit()
      }
    })
}
...
```

My function of my store module:
(api is a handler for axios, basicall axios. ...)

```js
update ({ commit, rootGetters }, details) {
  ...
  const requestUrl = `some adress`
  return api
    .patch(
      requestUrl,
      validatedDetails
    )
    .then(response => {
      return response
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    })
}
```

Other stackoverflow posts related to that problem, did answer my question, since in the examples are in one file and one method.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try someting like:

```
update ({ commit, rootGetters }, details) {
  ...
  const requestUrl = `some adress`
  return api.patch(
      requestUrl,
      validatedDetails
    )
}
```

and :

```
async saveEdit (event, targetProperty, updateValue) {
  try {
    const result = await this.update(this[updateValue])
    if (result.status === 200) {
      this.fetchData()
      this.cancelEdit()
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // handle api call error
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, that was what I was looking for.
I totally forgot about try/catch (never used it in action).
Thanks again, was a greate help